# Vercel taking a loong time to deploy (Command "npm install" exited with 254) error

Tags: node.js, github, deployment, vercel

code -> https://github.com/vovafish/personal-site

I am trying to deploy my nodejs react app but it just taking ages. I am not sure what I did wrong. I don't think it even building it.

Log:

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-04T11_47_39_033Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 254

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node output/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config output/server.js",
    "build": "tsc -watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

The way I specified 'em in the vercel settings.
[image]

p.s. i don't have vercel.json since it is not required so i dont think it can lead to an errro